# Doing multithreading implicitly?

Tags: multithreading, cpu

I have a question from one of my IT-subjects. Actually I am trying to understand **multithreading**, and the one question that I need answer to is

> what can be done if we want to activate multiple Threads when our
>   Hardwaresystem doesn't support explict multithreading solutions

(also don't know what solutions fall into that category.)

Any help on understandig the whole multithreading is welcome and particulary answer on this question :)
Thank you!

Comment: you can simulate multithreading on a single thread, look up [Green Threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads), they basically do that. or check out Google Go's goroutines, when GOMAXPROCS is set to 1, Go basically simulates multithreading on a single hardware thread

Comment: Green Threads seems to be one possible answer, but  can you tell me does any of these also are a possible choice: superscalar processor, SMT, Multicore Processor, VLIW (very long instruction word) ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @hanshenrik, there is nothing "simulated" about green threads. Green threads are threads---different execution paths through the code that happen concurrently. Using green threads requires the programmer to be aware of a slightly different list of dos and don'ts as compared to preemptively scheduled threads, but the basic idea of several different, concurrent execution contexts, each with its own call stack, remains the same.

Comment: @SolomonSlow on a single hardware thread, like the one in OP's scenario, green threads don't run concurrently. even tho you may get the impression that they're running concurrently because the green thread scheduler may switch between giving cpu time to different threads very fast, it's in fact only 1 thread that runs at any given time with only 1 hardware thread. and to quote wikipedia, `Green threads emulate multithreaded environments without relying on any native OS abilities`  - maybe i should have said `emulated` instead of `simulated`, but not a native speaker, don't know the difference.

Comment: @hanshenrik, "Concurrent" doesn't mean the same as "parallel." Parallel execution is only possible on a host that has multiple CPUs, but "concurrent execution" merely means that more than one task is in a started-but-not-yet-finished state. Threads were invented as a way to model concurrent tasks--mostly on small, embedded, single-CPU systems. The use of threads for parallel computation only came later when multi-CPU servers and workstations became a commercial reality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it makes any sense to talk about *implicit* multi-threading.

Multi-threading is a way to structure computer software such that a single program can have several different, independent activities going on at the same time.  There are several different reasons why you would want to do that, but none of them happens by accident. Multi-threaded programs only exist because somebody *intentionally* wrote them that way.

---

One of the reasons for writing a multi-threaded program is to perform *[parallel computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing)* on a multi-CPU host.  Other technologies that you mentioned, "superscalar, SMT, VLIW," are all different approaches to parallelism.

My guess is, that when you said "multithreading" in your question, you actually were asking about parallelism.